# Render only SVG nodes of data that is currently visible?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have created a line chart which is zoom/pan enabled, however I am now using "real" data which consists of 60,000+ points and the performance has not surprisingly crashed to 1 - 2 fps.

Does anyone have an approach to render only what is visible when zoomed/panned? I'm nervous to use html5 canvas, is it even possible to use canvas for a line chart with a time domain?

Comment: paste code that you have tried or fiddle

Comment: Chrome and Firefox (and probably most other UAs) already do that optimisation for you.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox definitely are not handling this well, i'm getting 1 - 2 fps. I've also tried simplify.js but eve at max tolerance it struggles! I am not permitted to post the actual code.

Comment: If you're not permitted to show the exact code, please outline approximately the technique you're using to render (even in English), and where you see a potential for this optimisation.

Comment: I'm saying that it's the simple existence of 60,000 elements in the DOM that's slow. That's what you need to address, rather than the rendering. You need to load fewer points unzoomed and then when you zoom, increase the resolution by requesting more data from the server.

Comment: im aware that it is due to 60,000 elements, that is why the title is what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update.

I'm now using crossfilter.js to filter my data. My basic method, in my zoom handler I filter my whole dataset based on the x.domain() extent (lower and upper boundary) values CrossFilter creates a new array containing only the data that fits into the new domain. This new array is passed to my update function which renders only the visible data!

Also it is worth noting that even HTML5 canvas was struggling to render even 60k points fast enough. At around 90k it stopped working entirely!